# Application Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives

Let $k:[a,b]\times[a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$, $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$. 
$$
f(x)=\int\limits_a^x k(x,y)\phi(y)\mathrm{d}y \qquad a\le x \le b
$$
I have to compute $f'(x)$.

I don't know how to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in this case.

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=k(x,x)\phi(x)+\int_0^x \phi(y)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}k(x,y)dy.$$

In general, if 
$$f(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}k(g(x),y)\phi(y)dy,$$
you get
$$f'(x)=b'(x)k(g(x),b(x))\phi(b(x))-a'(x)k(g(x),a(x))\phi(a(x))+g'(x)\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\phi(y)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}k(g(x),y)dy.$$

Comment: Thank you very much Surb. But I still can't understand from where this formula comes from